# How does the "if exist" command work in Windows batch scripts?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

In Windows batch scripts, usually we can find `if exist xxx` or `if not exist xxx`.

Does this search all files in the computer, or any specific folder or path, for the `xxx` specified?

Answer (score 5):

If you have not specified a folder, it will look in current folder.
But you can work use wildcards.
Example:

```
if exist *.png echo There are images here
```

will output the text if in the current folder there are any files with the extension .png

or you can specify a full path, for example

```
if exist d:\temp\*.png echo There are images there
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, so it will search a certain path! I got it!

Answer (score 0):

if you want it to check if something exist. and then make it execute something afterwards. then this is how you do it:

```
if exist "D:randomstuff\random\ranodom\allala.jpg" goto anotherLabel
if not exist "D:randomstuff\random\ranodom\allala.jpg" goto addwrite
:anotherlabel
:addwrite
MKDIR D:randomstuff\random\ranodom\
    echo this image doesn't exist> D:randomstuff\random\ranodom\allala.txt



or you can do this:
if exist randomfile.txt (
    for /f %%A in (randomfile.txt) do set text=%%A
    ) else (
    goto notexist.
```

basically what you do. you insert the path to whatever file you want it to check if exist (with file name)
and then you just set it to do an actionl wether its to create, add in, overwrite, copy, change label. etc.

Comment: Thank you for your answer ! :)